# compare today's date with list of scheduled notifications using scheduled notifications array in iphone

Tags: objective-c, notifications, nsarray

I got list of all scheduled notifications using 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications].

Now i want array of all firedates to compare it with today's date and give an alertview telling the due today reminder.
i did it by this way but am not sure whether it will work fine. please correct me as am new to iphone development.

```
NSArray *arrayoflocalnotifications = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]];

for (UILocalNotification *localnotif in arrayoflocalnotifications)
{
     NSLog(@"array of firedate is %@", localnotif);

    if ([localnotif.fireDate isEqualToDate:[NSDate date]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Got a duetoday reminder...");

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"Due reminder for today" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use compare: function to compare two different dates. Use it like;

```
if(localnotif.fireDate compare:[NSDate date] == NSOrderedSame){
 // perform your operation here
}
```

**compare:** gives you flexibility to compare if the date is before or after certain date by comparing it to **NSOrderedAscending/NSOrderedDescending**.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but am confused, how can i show those matching  firedates in my tableview and an alertview as well.

Comment: hey @insane-36 i solved it like this- converting today's date and firedate from arrayoflocalnotifications in string format and comparing we can get reminders/notifications which will fire today.